# the purpose of default constructor

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C#, just a question on default constructor.
I was reading a book which says

> the default constructor ensures that all field data of the class is set to an appropriate default value

Let's say we have the following class:

```
class Employee
{
   public string name;
   public int empID;
   public Employee(string name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
...
static void Main(string[] args){
   Employee emp = new Employee("Michael");
   Console.WriteLine(emp.empID);
}
```

and the output is 0, which means `empID` has been initialized to its default value.
But I didn't initialize the `empID` in the constructor nor do I have a default constructor(override by given constructor), so why `empID` still get initialized?

**a quick Update**:

for those who said it won't compile, because I copied the wrong thing originally, it should work now

[image]

again, my question is, why the text book says the **default constructor ensures** that all field data of the class is set to an appropriate **default value** but in my case there is **no default constructor involved** while empID still got its default value?

Comment: That code will not compile.

Comment: Code shown can't compile... So who knows why you see whatever you claim happening.

Comment: `empID` has a not nullable value type (int). So it "always" has a value. If not initialized differently it gets the default value 0.

Comment: @SᴇM    could you just give a try before making an assumption that it won't compile?

Comment: @slowjams Who said I made an assumption? In normal circumstances, this code will not compile.

Comment: @SᴇM how come it did compile on my VS 2017 .NET 4.6.1?

Comment: @slowjams [here you go](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31I4oi).

Comment: If it compiles at your end, that means you are not sharing the complete code here. Whatever code you have shared won't compile for sure.. Employee class does not have default constructor and you are trying to use one in Program.Main method... that's why it won't compile...@slowjams

Comment: Aaaand `Program.cs`?

Comment: @SEM sorry I didn't copy the parameter in the program.cs, please have a look at my updated post

Comment: Check the answer from @MichaelTurczyn below to understand why EmpId is 0

Comment: @slowjams i've copied and pasted your code.  Unsurprisingly it doesn't compile. It has the exact same error as in the fiddle supplied by SeM

Comment: @Mick After the last question update the posted code should be fine. Please refresh

Comment: It is a nice guarantee you get in C#, even if you don't write a default constructor then you can still be sure that fields get their default value.  Which is 0 or null.  This often helps you skip writing a bunch of code in your own default constructor.  Or allows skipping writing one completely, ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

First, this won't compile, because you didn't define default constructor - when you define constructor with parameters, default one becomes unavailable, unless you define it explicitly. So you need to use `new Employee("some name");`

Second, `empID` has default value `0`, so it is expected, that after using default construcotr (which is unavailable, as I said) it has value of `0`.

Generally deefault value for value types are `0` (when we talk about numeric types, for other value types, like `DateTime`, see documentation) and for reference types it's `null`.

Comment: sorry I copied the wrong code in main method, could you have a another look, this time there is no default constructor

Comment: @slowjams My answer is still valid

Comment: so why the book said the default constructor ensures that all field data of the class is set to an appropriate default value. there is no default constructor in my case and emp still gets the default value?

Comment: @slowjams Because this is true for all kinds of constructors :) not only for default

Comment: @slowjams If you look at warning messages or hover on `empID` field (green warning underline), you will see something like this: _"Field 'Program.Employee.empID' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0"_.

Comment: @slowjams Mentioned content in the book is wrong and it should be any constructor  is used to set the default values of the data members of the class. May I know which book is that.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for C# constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors) is actually a bit poorly worded. It says:

> If a class does not have a constructor, a parameterless constructor is automatically generated **and** default values are used to initialize the object fields. For example, an int is initialized to 0.

The "**and**" here seems to indicate that this only happens if you don't provide a constructor, and then ... what happens? ... if you do provide a constructor?

**The answer is that all instance fields are initialized.** Regardless of the presence of a developer-defined constructor, default or otherwise.

---

It is actually not the constructor(s) that initialize fields to their default value, ie. 0 for numeric fields, `null` for references, etc.

This is done by `new` operator, *before* constructors are involved.

If you have this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Field;
}
```

Then no constructor will specifically store anything into the `Field` field, it will be initialized to 0 when the memory is allocated for the instance.

If, instead, you have this constructor:

```
public Test()
{
    Field = 42;
}
```

or you have this field declaration:

```
public int Field = 42;
```

(which amounts to the same thing)

Then what happens when you construct an instance of this type is that the memory is being allocated, *and set to 0*, which will set the initial value for `Field` to 0, and then the constructor will be invoked which will set the field to 42.

Comment: I do not see the parameter less constructor for the my class as you can see in my answer.

Comment: If you provide a constructor of your own, no default constructor will be added by the compiler. That does not mean that the fields will not be initialized, however. They still are.

Comment: Yes I agree with that

Answer (score 0):

While initializing the instance of a class the compiler needs to know the space it needs to allocate for this type instance in the memory and the same is achieved by calculating the space of the instance variables or data member field and then the type’s instance constructor is called to set the initial state of the object.

When constructing a reference type object, the memory allocated for the object is always zeroed out before the type’s instance constructor is called. 
Any fields that the constructor doesn’t explicitly overwrite are guaranteed to have a value of 0 or null.

Below is a sample class which I created without default or parameter less constructor.

```
public class PersonWithoutDefault
{       
    private string name;      
    public PersonWithoutDefault(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And below figure shows the disassembled code using ildasm. There is no default or parameter less constructor.

[image]